# Linuxでシンボリックリンクの参照先となっているかどうかを確認する方法はありますか？

Tags: linux

表題の通り、Linux（CentOS)を利用しておりますが、あるディレクトリに対して、シンボリックリンクの参照先となっているかどうか確認する方法はございますか？
　
`/usr/local/` の配下にopenjdkを下記のように配置しております。

```
jdk -> /usr/local/jdk-19.0.2
jdk-19
jdk-19.0.1
jdk-19.0.2
```

PATH には `/usr/local/jdk` を設定して、Javaを利用するプログラムには、バージョンを気にしないようにしております。

古いバージョンのフォルダを定期的に削除しておりますが、いざ削除しようとしたとき、本当に削除して問題はないのか？と思うようになりました。
環境自体共用のサーバなので、自分以外の者が、勝手にjdk-19のJDKを見るようなプログラムを実装する可能性もあります。

ルート(`/`)からシンボリックリンクを探して確認すればよいのですが、もっと簡単な方法はないのでしょうか？
ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらアイデアをいただければと思います。

Comment: シンボリックリンクの参照先が同じ位置 ("/usr/local/") かどうか, ということですか？

Comment: 削除したいディレクトリが、シンボリックリンクの参照先として指定されているかどうかを確認する方法について教えていただきたいと思います。  
先ほどの例ですと、/usr/local/jdk-19.0.1というディレクトリを削除したいとして  
実は/var/test/の配下に、  
  jdk -> /usr/local/jdk-19.0.1  
というシンボリックリンクが存在している場合です。
私が、/usr/local/jdk-19.0.1を削除すると、/var/test/jdkのリンクは無効になり、  
/usr/test/jdkを参照するプログラムに影響が出ます。/usr/local/jdk19.0.1は別のシンボリックリンクの参照先になっていることを簡単にわかる方法がないかと質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

シンボリックリンクには参照先情報はあるけど, 「どこから参照されている」の情報はありません
なので, (例えば)以下のようなコマンドを用いキャッシュしておき, 必要に応じて検索するとよいかも

- $ `find /usr/local/ -type l`
- $ `ls -lR /usr/local/ | grep ^l`

ハードリンクという手もあります
ハードリンクを作成するのであれば, 複数存在するかどうかは少なくともわかります (`ls -l` とかで)

Comment: シンボリックリンクは、参照元情報は管理されていないこと。そのために事前に検索する方法ありがとうございます。また、ハードリンクは盲点でした。

Answer (score 1):

oririさんの回答にあるように、シンボリックリンクの参照元の情報はファイルシステム上で管理されていないです。

Linux環境であればreadlink(1)を使うと、シンボリックリンクを再帰的にたどって末端のファイルを見つけることができるようです。

```
find / -type l  -print -exec readlink -f {} \; | paste - -
```

例えば以上を実行するとシンボリックリンクのファイルと末端のファイルのペアを表示できるので、grepで絞り込めば、調べたいファイルを直接または間接的にシンボリックリンクしているファイルが見つかると思います。

Comment: シンボリックリンクの参照元情報はファイルシステム上管理されていないこと承知しました。また、readlinkの使い方についてありがとうございます。さっそく試してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

GNU find コマンドの `-samefile` オプションを利用する場合。
※ root directory から探索すると時間が掛かる場合がありますので、可能であれば探索開始ディレクトリを限定するか、`-xdev` オプションや `-fstype` オプションなどを付ける方がよいでしょう。

```bash
$ cd /tmp
$ touch foo
$ (cd /var/tmp && ln -s ../../tmp/foo .; ls -l foo)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nemo nemo 13 Feb  8 18:45 foo -> ../../tmp/foo

$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0

$ find -L / -xdev -samefile /tmp/foo 2>/dev/null
/var/tmp/foo
/tmp/foo
```

Comment: GNU findを使っています。試しに、-xdev , -samefileオプション使って試してみましたが、探索は断然早いですね。探索開始ディレクトリはある程度狭められるので、それで事前に探索して、削除できるかどうか判断したいと思います。